# I need to set a progress bar that shows percentage according to execution of lines

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, progress-bar

In by vb.net form, I have some 300 lines of code that performs various operations.
Approximately it takes 40 to 60 seconds to complete based on given inputs. End users asked me, We don't know whether the process is undergone or hanged-up.

So, I need to display a progress bar which should gradually increase according to the execution of code.

During the execution of 75th line, the progress should display loaded upto 25%.
During the execution of 225th line, the progress should display loaded upto 75%.

So, How to achieve that.. Can we achieve that by using Thread ? If yes, how can I ?? I am new for Thread.

Comment: Start by googling background worker and progress bar

Comment: Set the progress bar's `Maximum` property to `300`, then increment its `Value` property by 1 after every line. There is no way for the application to know which line it is currently at, so you have to do it manually.